# how to implement quest pointer guide in godot 3?

Tags: godot

I am making a 2d platformer.(using gdscript)
I have been trying to make a guide arrow that shows you where to go  and have been failing. I far as I can see there is no godot tutorial for this yet.
I have however managed to find a unity tutorial but have been having a hard time converting the instructions to godot.
https://youtu.be/dHzeHh-3bp4
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As a general piece of advice, there will not always be a tutorial for the specific thing you want. You need to get a good grasp of the essentials (control flow, signals, how the scene tree operates), and then you'll be able to come up with these things yourself, without having to consult a guide every time.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the indicator is a `Sprite` with whatever icon you want to show.

By the way, you are going to need a reference to the `Camera2D`. *Unlike in 3D where you can ask Godot for the current `Camera`, you will have to handle references to the current `Camera2D` yourself.*

I'll assume you already have the reference to the `Camera2D` (perhaps you have the code in the `Camera2D` script) and the reference to the indicator `Sprite` (which is another possible place to have the code).

I'll also assume you don't have a rotated `Camera2D`.

---

First we need the center of the screen:

```
var center := camera.get_camera_screen_center()
```

Then we can get the vector to the position we want:

```
var vec := target - center
```

Where `target` is the position in global coordinates you want to point to. *By the way, if `vec` is `Vector2.ZERO`, then the target at the center of the screen.*

Let us `clamp` it by the size of the `Viewport`. We are going to use half the size since we are measuring from the center of the screen. I'll also add a `margin`, I'll come back to that, for now, assume `margin = Vector2.ZERO`.

```
var helf_size := (get_viewport().size - margin) * 0.5
var clamped_vec := Vector2 (
        clamp(vec.x, -half_size.x, half_size.x),
        clamp(vec.y, -half_size.y, half_size.x)
    )
```

If those are equal, it means the target is on the screen (it didn't need to be clamped):

```
if clamped_vec == vec:
    # target on screen
    pass
else:
    # target out of screen
    pass
```

---

Now, to place the indicator we need two things: a rotation and a position, correct?

The rotation is easy. It is the angle of our `vec`:

```
sprite.global_rotation = vec.angle()
```

And for the position, well, it will be our `clamped_vec` except we need to place the indicator. So we need to add a... Margin! Aha! So, adjust the `margin` to the size of the indicator you have, and `clampled_vec` will give us the position, we just need to add `center` back:

```
sprite.global_position = clamped_vec + center
```

And that should do it.